# Код не доработан, он заходит на страницу ВК, но не выводит посты со стены

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
import vk_api


def main():
      """ An example of getting all posts from a wall """

      login, password = '', ''
      vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)

      try:
          vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
      except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
          print(error_msg)
          return

      tools = vk_api.VkTools(vk_session)

  

      wall = tools.get_all('wall.get', 100, {'itmascoldsiemens': 1})

      print('Posts count:', wall['count'])

      if wall['count']:
          print('First post:', wall['items'][0], '\n')
      if wall['count'] > 1:
          print('Last post:', wall['items'][-1])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Выдает ошибку Неизвестная ошибка аутентификации API
Я читал документацию ВК, читал Github, читал stackoferflow, но четкого решения проблемы так и не нашел.